# How Does a Rocket Even Go Up?

Tags: gravity, acceleration

The earth pulls all bodies towards it at $9.8\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$.  I would like to imagine that the ground is accelerating up at $9.8\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ (just as an analogy). So this means that a rocket going up should have a greater acceleration than $9.8\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ to go up. But that doesn't seem to be the case. I found out that any body with a force capable of lifting itself should be able to go up with any acceleration. But how? if the rocket's acceleration is less than $9.8$, then the ground should eventually catch up to it. That is, the rocket falls down right?

I wrote some code to run simulations on this and the result was the rocket eventually came down.

So where am I going wrong?

**TL;DR: how a body can move away from a body accelerating towards it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what do you mean by any force  capable of lifting itself, but In this case you cannot simply solve this problem by assuming gravity to be constant as the rocket goes to heights comparable to the radius of the Earth and hence the gravity changes. You have to apply conservation of Energy.Also adding to this, I'm sure you must have learnt that force acting on a body is proportional to the rate of change of momenttum. As momentum is mv, you can also change the mass to make the rocket accelerate and make the ground not catch up to it as per your analogy which is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for Explaining!

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of forces, $F = m \cdot a$, where $a$ is the acceleration towards the earth resulting from gravitation, and $m$ is the rocket's mass. $F$ is the gravitational force which pulls the rocket to the ground.  Forces also have a direction. The rocket needs a force in opposite direction, which is larger than the gravitational force, to overcome it and take off.

Comment: fine. to clear it up, is Gravity a force (Newtonian) or is it acceleration? (as einstein said)

Comment: @ARDUINOmakerDK7 Gravity is a fundamental force of nature, which, like all forces, causes acceleration of masses it acts upon. There is no real difference between the two except for a proportionality constant.

Answer (score 1):

The other ingredient left out above is what an orbit is.  Most of the energy of a (non-interplanetary) rocket isn't spent "making it go up", it is spent "getting it to go fast enough sideways"

The reason that this is important is that an orbit is basically, "you're going so fast, that by the time you've fallen, thanks to the curvature of the earth, you're at the same altitude (or higher) than you were before, and since you keep going, you never come back down.  That's basically what an orbit is.  Orbiting spacecraft have their engines turned off, because they are essentially going so fast that they never come back down.